# how to deactivate GO111MODULE

Tags: go, mpc

I was looking forward to knowing how to deactivate go mod

I was working with this sdk for multi-party-computation

https://fusion.org/tech/dcrm

Answer (score 1):

use

```
go env -w  GO111MODULE=off
```

then run

```
make bootnode 
make gdcrm
```